# Botón fijo se queda detrás en plantilla JQuery Mobile

Tags: css

¡Hola!, estoy teniendo problemas en implementar un botón fijo en una web con JQuery Mobile 1.4.5, y el problema está en que me queda detrás (ó debajo) de los elementos, por ejemplo, en la página hay una lista con que contiene vínculos, el botón queda fijo y aparentemente queda arriba pero al presionar el botón lo que se presiona no es el link del botón, sino del elemento de la lista (li) que está supuestamente debajo del botón, dejo la hoja del botón:

```
.z-depth-1, .btn, .btn-large, .btn-floating {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.z-depth-1-half, .btn:hover, .btn-large:hover, .btn-floating:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.btn, .btn-large,
.btn-floating,
.btn-large,
.btn-flat {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn i, .btn-large i,
.btn-floating i,
.btn-large i,
.btn-flat i {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.btn:focus, .btn-large:focus,
.btn-floating:focus {
  background-color: #1d7d74;
}

.btn, .btn-large {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #26a69a;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn, .btn-large,
.btn-flat {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.btn:hover, .btn-large:hover {
  background-color: #2bbbad;
}

.btn-floating {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.btn-floating i {
  width: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.btn-floating:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.btn-floating:before {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.btn-floating.btn-large {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
}

.btn-floating.btn-large i {
  line-height: 56px;
}

.fixed-action-btn-main {
  position: fixed;
  right: 23px;
  bottom: 23px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 998;
}

.fixed-action-btn-top {
  position: fixed;
  right: 30px;
  bottom: 85px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 998;
}

.material-icons {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
     -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
          font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}

i.large {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

Aquí dejo donde lo implemento:

```
<div data-role="page" id="principal" data-theme="d" data-url="principal">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>LigaBillarCdE</h1>
        <a href="#left-panel" data-theme="d" data-icon="bars" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" class="ui-icon-nodisc">Open left panel</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">
        <div>
            <select id="games_filter">
                <option value="0">Filtrar Juegos</option>
                <option value="25">Últimos 25</option>
                <option value="all">Todos</option>
            </select>           
        </div>
        <div id="no-games" class="nodata" style="display: none;"><p>No hay partidas que mostrar</p></div>
        <div id="games_content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="games_list" data-divider-theme="a"></ul>
        </div>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div class="fixed-action-btn-top">
        <a id="sync_games" class="btn-floating">
            <i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
        </a>
    </div>  
    <div class="fixed-action-btn-main">
        <a id="new_game" href="#create-modal" class="btn-floating btn-large">
            <i class="large material-icons">add</i>
        </a>
    </div>  

    <!-- panel de menú -->
    <div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-overlay ui-body-b ui-panel-animate ui-panel-open">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li data-icon="false"><div id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div></li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a href="#players-list"><img src="img/players.png" class="ui-li-icon">Jugadores</a></li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a href="#modals-ranking"><img src="img/ranking.png" class="ui-li-icon">Ranking</a></li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a href="#modal-list"><img src="img/modals.png" class="ui-li-icon">Modalidades</a></li>
            <li data-icon="false"><a href="#" id="close-app"><img src="img/exit.png" class="ui-li-icon">Cerrar App</a></li>
        </url>
    </div><!-- /panel -->   
</div>
```

He tratado de jugar con el z-index y position entre el div con data-role content y el botón pero nada me funciona!!.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la respuesta de x-rw, me dió una pista, el problema estaba en una de las reglas de JQuery Mobile, específicamente la regla .ui-panel-wrapper, lo pude corregir de esta manera:

```
.ui-panel-wrapper {
   z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

Con eso se resuelve el problema.